# Using subquery with mysql error

Tags: mysql

Hey guys am new to mysql and i have been trying some code without using any table name in `from` in mysql with a subquery.

I have selected two table in the form like

```
select * from
(select id from
 (select AGE) somename ) v
```

My table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   id   INT              NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2), 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)  
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5);
```

I know this is stupid idea ..But i just want to know wheather it can be done by selecting the subquery without using table name..

Thanx in advance..

Comment: Since `AGE` is a column rather than a string or numeric literal value, you will need a `FROM` clause. Can you post a small sample of what you would expect the query output to be? That would help us understand your intent a little better.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get the `AGE` value `WHERE name = 'somename'`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i just dont care output actually ..i just want to  know can this be use with three subqueries like i mentioned below without specifiying the table name

Comment: No its not possible.

Comment: @almasshaikh so do i need to add the table name ..so you are saying that i cant get any output without specifying the table name ??

Comment: MySQL allows (some other RDBMS don't) you to do things like `SELECT NOW()` for the current time, or `SELECT 'A string'` for the string's value, or `SELECT REPLACE('ABC','A','Z')` all without a `FROM`, because none is dependent on a table value. But dependence on a table like `SELECT AGE` requires a `FROM`.

Comment: @saptamasree It isn't clear enough what your intent is though, because the components you have here `SELECT *`, `SELECT id`, `SELECT AGE` don't have an apparent relationship.

Comment: Yes if you need something from your table to be very precise then yes its not possible without table name.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i just want to know can this query be made work without mentioning the table name ..if yes .please write it up as an answer..it can be by using two or 3 sub queries without mentioning table name

Comment: @saptamasree I generally don't write answers as "no you can't do that" because it may change or I may just be wrong, but MySQL here _must_ have the table name in one of the `FROM` clauses. Without it, it has no idea where to look for these values -- unless you went first looking in `information_schema.COLUMNS` for columns named `AGE` regardless of their table of origin. But still that requires `information_schema.COLUMNS` in a `FROM` clause.